# RGLPK Solver in R Issue

Tags: r, optimization, solver

I am trying to teach myself R and utilize some code I found via this site for a fantasy football type project. I am trying to get the total cost, projected points and the selected people to display. But, I know I must be doing something wrong. When I try to replicate the code and use RGLPK as a solver, I get the following results in the 
Console of RStudio:

```
>     PlayerData[sol$solution ==1,]
[1] Name       Salary     Team       Position   Opponent   Ceiling    Floor      Projection
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
>     sprintf('Cost is:$%i', sum(PlayerData$Salary[sol$solution > 0]))
[1] "Cost is:$0"
>     sprintf('Projected Points is $%obj', sol$optimum)
[1] "Projected Points is $0bj"
```

I am trying to get the total cost, projected points and the selected people to display. But, I know I must be doing something wrong. Here is the code I am trying to use:

```
library(Rglpk)

PlayerData <- read.csv("NFLDKData.csv")

 num.players <- length(PlayerData$Name)
 obj <- PlayerData$Projection
 var.types <- rep("B", num.players)

matrix <- rbind(as.numeric(PlayerData$Position == "QB"), # num QB
            as.numeric(PlayerData$Position == "RB"), # num RB
            as.numeric(PlayerData$Position == "RB"), # num RB
            as.numeric(PlayerData$Position == "WR"), # num WR
            as.numeric(PlayerData$Position == "WR"), # num WR
            as.numeric(PlayerData$Position == "TE"), # num TE
            as.numeric(PlayerData$Position == "TE"), # num TE
            as.numeric(PlayerData$Position %in% c("RB", "WR", "TE")),  # Num RB/WR/TE
            as.numeric(PlayerData$Position == "DEF"),# num DEF
            PlayerData$Salary)                       # total cost

direction <- c("==",
           ">=",
           "<=",
           ">=",
           "<=",
           ">=",
           "<=",
           "==",
           "==",
           "<=")


rhs <- c(1, # Quartbacks
     2, # RB Min
     3, # RB Max
     3, # WR Min
     4, # WR Max
     1, # TE Min
     2, # TE Max
     7, # RB/WR/TE
     1, # Defense
     50000)                # By default, you get 50K to spend 



sol <- Rglpk_solve_LP(obj = obj, mat = matrix, dir = direction, rhs = rhs,
                  types = var.types, max = TRUE)

PlayerData[sol$solution ==1,]
sprintf('Cost is:$%i', sum(PlayerData$Salary[sol$solution > 0]))
sprintf('Projected Points is $%obj', sol$optimum)
```

I am a bit of a loss and could use some expert advice. Appreciate anyone willing to help. And, thank you in advance.

Comment: what is `PlayerData$Projection`? I could see that in your code except in objective.

Comment: It was just the projected score of the player for that week. 
Ex Header: Name Salary Team Position Opponent Ceiling Floor Projection 
Data in those columns:
Patrick Mahomes 7500 KCC QB HOU 34.576 12.966 21.61

Comment: I wanted to ask how is this obj related to the variables which is essential for any optimization problem?

Comment: To reproduce the problem, the contents of `NFLDKData.csv` are needed.

Comment: What is the best way to load the CSV? It is a pretty simple file with the columns I mentioned above and the sample data in those columns. For example, each player has a projected score. In the above example...Patrick Mahomes is projected at 21.61 pts. That is the PlayerData$Projection column. Each player's projected score.